# Alternative to WPF WebBrowser control that can support ActiveX?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control

In my WPF application I need to host a web browser control that can support JavaScript and ActiveX.

This browser will open 3D HTML files (heavy files) based on catia model.

I need to open them in a reasonable time... this is my issue right now.

My goal is to be as close as possible of these time: (this is the time Internet Explorer needs to open each file)

- Sample 1 (Light 3D file) : 12 seconds
- Sample 2 (Medium 3D file) : 84 seconds
- Sample 3 (Heavy 3D file) : 160 seconds

If I use the WPF WebBrowser control, these are my time:

- Sample 1 (Light HTML 3D file) : 23 seconds
- Sample 2 (Medium HTML 3D file) : 195 seconds
- Sample 3 (Heavy HTML 3D file) : 367 seconds

So as you can see, the WebBrowser hosted in my simple WPF application takes a lot of time to load my files...

If there is no alternate control that I can use... is there a way to accelerate the loading with the WPF WebBrowser?

I found on Internet other web browser for WPF but none of them works with our 3D html (activeX).

Comment: In my experience hosting web content in a WPF app, the WebBrowser control was far from great, but it was the only viable option I could find.  I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but I believe the WebBrowser control is just the WinForms WebBrowser with some WPF "wrapping" around it.  Have you tried to see if the performance characteristics are different if you use the WinForms host control to host a WinForms browser control directly?  Not sure, but just a thought.

Comment: Does not meet host part of the requirement but you could launch IE as a separate process.  That ActiveX part going back a few layers.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Blam: no I cannot launch IE as a separate process